# How to solve this recurrence equation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

[image]

I am not entirely sure on how to start solving this problem. Do I try to divide (n-1) from both sides to get T(n) on one side?

Comment: You are asked to use repeated substitutions, aren't you ? See the hint by ThomasGrubb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align*}
T(n)&=\frac{n}{n-1}T(n-1)+(n+1)n\\
&=\frac{n}{n-1}\left(\frac{n-1}{n-2}T(n-2)+n(n-1)\right)+(n+1)n\\
&=\frac{n}{n-2}T(n-2)+n^2+(n+1)n\\
&=\frac{n}{n-2}\left(\frac{n-2}{n-3}T(n-3)+(n-1)(n-2)\right)+n^2+(n+1)n\\
&=\frac{n}{n-3}T(n-3)+(n-1)n+n^2+(n+1)n\\
&=\dots
\end{align*}

Comment: I upvoted for the use of repeated substitutions, but this is only a hint, not a solution.

Comment: Awesome. I tried the same thing and got this, but I'm stuck on the pattern.  How do I simplify the rest of this?

I usually have trouble find the pattern for the general solution and finishing off the summation if there is one. I know it comes with practice, but any other tips?

Answer (score 1):

Divide throughout by $n(n-1)$ to get
$$\frac{T(n)}{n} = \frac{T(n-1)}{n-1} + n+1 $$
Now, put $S(n) = \frac{T(n)}{n}$. $S(n)$ has the recurrence relation
$$S(n) = S(n-1) + n+1$$
Hence $S(n) = 3+4+ \cdots + (n+1) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} - 3 = \frac{n^2+3n-4}{2} = \frac{(n-1)(n+4)}{2}$
and $T(n) = nS(n) = \frac{n(n-1)(n+4)}{2}$